# Как правильно настроить Django для работы с Telepot

Tags: django, telegram-bot, telegram, telepot

Подскажите пожалуйста как заставить их работать?
Читал эту статью: https://khashtamov.com/ru/create-telegram-bot-in-python/

Не совсем понятно как получать on_callback_query?

Answer (score 0):

Это функция определённого формата, которую можно написать самому:

```
def on_callback_query(msg):
    query_id, from_id, query_data = telepot.glance(msg, flavor='callback_query')
    print ('Callback Query:', query_id, from_id, query_data)
```

И затем передать Telepot'у для обработки сообщений:

```
bot = telepot.Bot(TOKEN)
bot.message_loop({'chat': on_chat_message,
                  'callback_query': on_callback_query,
                  'inline_query': on_inline_query,
                  'chosen_inline_result': on_chosen_inline_result})
```

Такие примеры можно найти [на этой странице](https://github.com/mx-wll/telepot-1).